# How can I animate a Marker when I put it on the map?

Tags: android-maps-v2

I would like to add a small animation to my markers when I put them on the map.
Just in the moment when I call:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(...);
```

Something like a small bounce or similar during half second or so.
I don't find the way to get the Marker's view.
If I find the way to get the view, I guess it is easy to apply an animation using `View.setAnimation()` and `res/animator/marker_animation.xml`

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this good video that shows markers animations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ

You can't animate the "Marker View" itself because it not accessible

Comment: Thanks. It's incredible how difficult is to do that in Android. In iOS is about 2 or 3 code lines.